# jquery and google maps v3 dragstart and dragend

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, drag, marker

I am creating an array of markers and attaching functionality to dragstart and dragend. I finally got it to work with a simple change, but cannot understand why the original code I created does not work.

For each marker the following code runs:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(evt){
    GLOBAL.startDragPosition = this.getPosition();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){
    if (confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Move this marker NOW ??")) {
        //do something here ...
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(GLOBAL.startDragPosition);
        delete GLOBAL.startDragPosition;            
    }
});
```

If I cancel the move, a different marker moves back to the original location. If I change the else statement to the following it works -

```
    } else {
        this.setPosition(GLOBAL.startDragPosition);
        delete GLOBAL.startDragPosition;            
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why the "marker." notation is not referring to the marker being dragged?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){
    if (confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Move this marker NOW ??")) {
        //do something here ...
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(GLOBAL.startDragPosition);
        delete GLOBAL.startDragPosition;            
    }
});
```

Is not how closures work.  The `marker` variable is not actually passed into the `function(evt) {}`.  My hunch is you are defining marker some place else multiple times.  Think of the function as a block of code that will be executed once a `'dragend'` even is observed on the marker as it was defined when you set up the listener.

Comment: That makes sense - the way I was looking at it "marker" was being sent into the function--- Thank you! Now I see what you mean :)